# Posting an array of Guid pairs to an Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ynSY6/3/), I'm allowing a user to dynamically create a table of data, and storing the ids of the table in a hidden field (in the example it's a text area so you can see it, and the final solution will be Guid rather than integers).

My question is simply this: What data type should I use on the server/MVC action to take the data held in the textarea/hidden field?

At the moment I have a string, and am contemplating doing a load of .split()'ing and whatnot, but it doesn't feel right!

Ultimately I need some sort of `IEnumerable<Guid, Guid>` thing?!?! so I can do a foreach and get each pair of Ids.

I'm sure the answer will be simple, but I can't think of what to do.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is broken. The `taskWayPointsGrid` variable is not declared anywhere.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov : Thanks it was pointing to an old revision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your UI has multiple, like-named form fields, they will be submitted to your action method and bound properly to an array. We could use `string[]` for this case.

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" name="guids"/>
  <input type="text" name="guids"/>
  <input type="text" name="guids"/>
  <input type="text" name="guids"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Then your controller could handle them like so:

```cs
public ActionResult MyAction(string[] guids)
{
    guids.Count == 4 // if all four fields were filled in.
}
```

Note that if there is just a single `guids` value sent by the form, the `string[] guids` will still work - it will contain just a single item.

Finally, note that if no values are entered, the array value will be null, not an empty array.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply.  Do you know if I can rely on the sort order in which string[] will be populated?

Comment: I've always seen it come in document order, but I'm not 100% sure if all browsers will do it that way all the time. MVC binds them in the order they appear in the request data.

Comment: I thought that would be the case.  Many thanks for all your help.

Comment: @ETFairfax Oh, one more thing: If no values are submitted, things could be weird. The array will be *null*, not empty. Also, be sure the array variable isn't part of the route.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually bind to a list from your model, take a look at this post

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx